# What are more examples of functions whose input and output have a constant product?

Tags: functions

I was recently thinking about functions and asked myself what would happen if a function had the property that $a\cdot f(a)$ = $b\cdot f(b)$ for any real numbers $a$ and $b$. My initial train of thought led me to conclude that the only function that satisfies that is $f(x)=0$. My reasoning was that since $a\cdot f(a)$ = $b\cdot f(b)$ no matter what values you use for $a$ and $b$, that the input and output of the function must have a constant product, meaning $x\cdot f(x)=c$ for any real number x and some constant c. Then you plug in $x=0$ to get $0\cdot f(0)=c\Rightarrow 0=c$ so that $x\cdot f(x)=0$. But the only way that equation is true for all x is if $f(x)=0$.

But then I accidentally found a counterexample: $f(x)=\frac1x$
$$a\cdot f(a)=b\cdot f(b)$$
$$a\cdot \frac1a=b\cdot \frac1b$$
$$1=1$$

In my argument, I plugged in $x=0$ so that $0\cdot f(0)=0$ since any zero times any real number is zero, but I guess that assumes that f(x) is even defined for $x=0$. This leaves me with two questions. What are some more examples of functions that fit this property besides $f(x)=0$? And are there any of those which **are** defined for $x=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any pair of real values $A,B$, the function

$$f_{A,B}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{A}{x}&x\neq 0\\ B&x=0\end{cases}$$ satisfies your condition.

But not only that, you can also show that those are **all** the functions that satisfy your condition. Take any function $f$ that has the property, and take any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Then, $1\cdot f(1)=x\cdot f(x)$, meaning that $$f(x)=\frac{1\cdot f(1)}{x} = \frac{A}{x}$$ for $A=f(1)$. So, this arbitrary function that satisfies your condition is in fact the function $f_{A,B}$ for $A=f(1)$ and $B=f(0)$.